# how to get the selected Options Value from the Table in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html

I have dynamically created a table in asp.net and Each cell in a row contains Option Button and Text Box respectively.The Option Buttons in a row are grouped.So,Only one Option Button Can be selected in a row.My Table contains m columns and n rows.

Now i want to get the selected Option Button value in each row when the form is submitted.

[image]

Above Table Contains 3 rows and 4 columns.

row :1 -> contains header.
row :2 ->[2,0] is a option button,[2,1] is a text box,[2,2] is a Option,[2,3] is Text Box
.
.
.
Last Row -> is a sumbit button.

So Now i want to get the selected options button value of each row when submit button is pressed.

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try something like this**

Note: Here `tbl` is an instance of `HtmlTable` control

```
foreach (TableRow row in tbl.Rows)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in r.Cells)
            { 
                RadioButton r = c.FindControl("radiobuttonID");
                // find your radiobutton & get needed values from that
             }
        }
```